# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while testing a Realm app on Android 2.3.3 (API 10 Emulator)

Tags: java, android, realm, nosql

I've been learning realm for the past few days and today I decided to test an app I'm developing on Android using Realm, for backward compatibility.

Emulator details:

```
Name: Nexus_4_API_10_2.3.3

CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabi)
Path: /home/mush/.android/avd/Nexus_4_API_10_2.3.3.avd
Target: default [Default] (API level 10)
Skin: nexus_4
SD Card: 100M
hw.dPad: no
runtime.network.speed: full
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: Nexus 4
vm.heapSize: 64
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.gps: yes
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
image.androidVersion.api: 10
hw.audioInput: yes
image.sysdir.1: platforms/android-10/images/
tag.id: default
showDeviceFrame: yes
hw.camera.back: emulated
hw.mainKeys: no
```

The App crushes as soon as it launches citing LoginActivity.java as the source of the error. 
Logcat Snippet:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _package_name_.sessions.LoginActivity
                      at _package_name_.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:26)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

I then went ahead to comment out the snippet of code that calls the LoginActivity.java.

The snippet:

```
//Check whether there's an active session first
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if (sessionManager.isSessionActive()) {
            //Session is active => Launch the MainActivity
            Intent launchMainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(launchMainActivity);
        } else {
            //Session is inactive => Launch the LoginActivity
            Intent launchLogin = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(launchLogin);
            finish();
        }
```

This did not solve my issue. Instead, Logcat halts at this point and the app freezes at my splash screen.

Logcat:

```
D/RealmManager: Initializing Realm configuration.
D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 118 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0006
D/dalvikvm: VFY: dead code 0x0008-000c in Lcom/getkeepsafe/relinker/SystemLibraryLoader;.supportedAbis ()[Ljava/lang/String;
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/_package_name_/lib/librealm-jni.so 0x40513a90`
```

The app runs quite fine on android API level 24. Does this mean realm is backward incompatible?

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "_package_name_"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    compile 'dk.ilios:realmfieldnameshelper:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
}
```

What am I doing wrong? And how do I correct it. I'll appreciate any help.
PS: There appears to be no other question of this sort of StackOverflow. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121403/not-able-to-use-realmadapter-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution) comes close though.

Comment: It might actually be an issue with the emulator, and not Realm on old phones. Good question though, can you try Realm 1.0.0 just to be sure?

Comment: It seems to be some problems with ReLinker. What is the ABI of the emulator? Does it have any other native `so` files than realm?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, I've tried it as you suggested and the app crushes with the same `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` error. @beeender I've updated the question to answer your question.

Comment: @MushTheRookie Can you please try with a minimal project with Realm? No other dependencies, just one activity, open a Realm instance with one model class defined? I want to make sure if it is a problem with loading `.so` file.

Comment: @beeender It appears to be a problem loading the .so file. I say this because the minimal prject with Realm and a single Model class halts at this point (`D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/realm.trial.myrealm/lib/librealm-jni.so 0x405150a8`). It does not crash the app, it simply does not proceed beyond this point.

Comment: I won't be surprised if there is a bug in the simulator when loading the so file ... To confirm this, can you please try with any apk with a so build in (other than Realm :P )? Or you can just try some samples from here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk

Comment: @beeender. I tried the same app on a Genymotion Samsung Galaxy S running android 2.3.7 with the exact same result. I now doubt it's a bug with the emulator. I'm convinced otherwise.

Comment: @MushTheRookie I tried to make a project and run it on my API 10 emulator, it works fine. Maybe you can share your apk so i can try it? You can send it to help@realm.io . Also please put the SO link in the mail so we can find the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck on this one?

Comment: It seemed to resolve itself with the subsequent update. Also, I'm inclined to think it was an issue with the emulator...